# Visual Studio 2010 copying content files to custom directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resources, directory, copy, config

I've got a question about copying content files to custom directory in Visual Studio. In project I have folder  with to many config xml files for my components, in order to avoid duplicates. So to all other project I've added thus config files as link files with "Copy to output directory" property set to "Copy Always".

And everything was fine, worked as expected, till now. Currently I added WCF project, added config files the same way. But there is a little problem when this config files are copied to bin directory, but working directory for WCF is root directory of project. So all init methods now fail to execute.

Does anybody have ideas or workarounds of how to set custom directory to copy files for Visual Studio "Copy to output" property?

PS: Sorry for no code, can provide some screenshots by request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do the copy with a [post build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2s2128d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: That the only one solution, I've comed to. But was sure that Visual Studio has some kind of property like I need.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but are you after having it build your files in to one directory?

If I have multiple projects in on solution I'll have a main starting project build to it's standard destination

**bin\Debug**

then the other projects to build in to the same directory as my main.

**..\OriginalProjectNameHere\bin\Debug**

To get there right click on a project in your solution exploring and select **properties** then **build** and scroll down to **output path**

I may have misunderstood your question, sorry if this is no help.

Comment: Thanks for try, but I need only config files to be moved, all other resources and libraries should stay where they are.